# Data from the database won’t show on RecyclerView. The page crashes and goes two pages back (HomeActivity)

Tags: java, android, database, android-recyclerview

I’m trying to show my data in a RecyclerView, but my data won’t show. Whenever I open the page for the data to show, it just crashes and goes two pages back.

This is the code for my ToolActivity (where the data should show).

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ToolsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper myDB;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<String> toolId, toolName, toolModule, toolDescription;
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tools);

        myDB = new DBHelper(ToolsActivity.this);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        toolId = new ArrayList<>();
        toolName = new ArrayList<>();
        toolModule = new ArrayList<>();
        toolDescription = new ArrayList<>();

        storeDataInArrays();

        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(ToolsActivity.this, toolId, toolName, toolModule, toolDescription);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ToolsActivity.this));
    }

    void storeDataInArrays() {
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                toolId.add(cursor.getString(0));
                toolName.add(cursor.getString(1));
                toolModule.add(cursor.getString(2));
                toolDescription.add(cursor.getString(3));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for my CustomAdapter:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList tool_id, tool_name, tool_module, tool_description;

    CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList tool_id, ArrayList tool_name, ArrayList tool_module, ArrayList tool_description) {

        this.context = context;
        this.tool_id = tool_id;
        this.tool_name = tool_name;
        this.tool_module = tool_module;
        this.tool_description = tool_description;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.costum_item_list, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tool_id_txt.setText(String.valueOf(tool_id.get(position)));
        holder.tool_name_txt.setText(String.valueOf(tool_name.get(position)));
        holder.tool_module_txt.setText(String.valueOf(tool_module.get(position)));
        holder.tool_description_txt.setText(String.valueOf(tool_description.get(position)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tool_id.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tool_id_txt, tool_name_txt, tool_module_txt, tool_description_txt;
        LinearLayout

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tool_id_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toolID);
            tool_name_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toolName);
            tool_module_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toolModule);
            tool_description_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toolDescription);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my DBHelper file:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ToolRegister.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tool_register";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "toolsID";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "tools_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_MODULE = "tools_module";
    private static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "tools_description";


    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                        " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                             + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, "
                             + COLUMN_MODULE + " TEXT, "
                             + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addTools(String name, String module, String description) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_MODULE, module);
        cv.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

        if(result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    Cursor readAllData () {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if(db != null) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: "it just crashes" -- [use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html). If you do not understand what the stack trace means, edit your question and provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: Im sorry, crash may not be the correct word, the page just opened and closes my previous page as well